# nm-applet not running on startup

Tags: 14.04, mate

I have installed MATE on Ubuntu 14.04 and nm-applet doesn't run on startup despite being set as a startup application and being installed. When I log in, I am able to open up a terminal, type nm-applet, and then it works but not when I restart the computer.

Comment: It's a bug. I saw it on Launchpad, but now I can't find it again.

Comment: That's probably it. They need to get to fixing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing indicator-applet-complete solved this issue for me:

`sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete`

Comment: I don't think that's right. I re-added nm-applet from my Startup Applications and it fixed without having to install anything extra.