# How can I restore a network manager indicator that disappeared after an upgrade to 16.04?

Tags: networking, 16.04, upgrade, indicator

Upgrade from 14.04 went otherwise flawlessly.  All my existing wifi connections still connect without problem, however if I were looking for a new connection or wanted to get network information I would use the indicator.  After my upgrade to 16.04 there is no longer an indicator.  What am I missing?

ps shows

```
3086 ? 00:00:00 nm-applet
```

If I kill 3086 and type in nm-applet to restart, nothing happens, no output, no command prompt back.

I also realized that the two systems I have that had the same problem had something in common that wasn't true on the other 5 systems I upgraded.  The problematic systems both had ClassicMenu Indicator installed.  Could be a complete red herring but it also may be evidence.

Comment: @steeldriver Found it http://askubuntu.com/questions/537198/nm-applet-not-running-on-startup I never would have without your hint that it was called nm-applet.  If you want to answer referencing this question I'll accept it, otherwise I'll answer myself in a day or so.

Comment: Feel free to go ahead and post/accept your own answer - I don't know enough detail to post one myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was marked as a duplicate but was closer to my experience than the original and the only answer given solved the problem.

[nm-applet not running on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537198/nm-applet-not-running-on-startup)

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```